# I have received my visa to Ukraine. And I realised that one letter in my name was wrong

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, ukraine, vfs-global, new-delhi

The employees at VFS Ukraine in Delhi have misspelled my name wrong. I had submitted all my details perfectly. And now I've received my visa through courier. It's supposed to be ROBINSON SAHAYAM MANUEL. but they have written Sahayan instead of Sahayam. I have booked my flight already . It's in about 2 weeks time . I would really appreciate any help in this. Anyone who's experienced this before ? I have emailed the embassy. But I doubt they will read it. As I have previously written them before for some other matter. I have mailed the VFS global too. But no response. Can anyone tell me what will be appropriate for me to do now. ? I'ts frustrating that I have to pay for someone's else's mistakes. It was supposed to be their job. Any help in this matter will be appreciated.  I am worried that they will stop me from boarding the airplane. Or I will have to apply for a new visa all over again. As that would be a little problematic. ?

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could guide me what to do now.

Comment: Can somebody help ????

Comment: Contract the embassy. Normally embassies ask you to check if the visa has correct information when you receive the passport back. And in this case, it's not correct. Ask them if they can correct it quickly (on the same day?) because you have your flight coming up soon.